# URL Rewrite with 2 values

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I add 2nd value to this code, at the moment I have got only $1, but how do I modyfie this code to have it mypage.php?name=$1&name2=$2   ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^new-page-([^/]*)\.php$ mypage.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /mypage.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^\&]*)
RewriteRule ^mypage.php$ new-page-%1.php? [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Every part of the regexp that is enclosed in parenthesis will be stored in variables $1, $2, and so on.

For example, you can write:

`RewriteRule ^new-page-([^/]*)-(.*)\.php$ mypage.php?name=$1&name2=$2` [L]

Where $1 will be the part in first parenthesis and $2 the one in the second.

If you want a more specific help, give us some example url.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^new-page-([^/]*)-(.*)\.php$ mypage.php?name=$1&name2=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /mypage.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^\&]*)
RewriteRule ^mypage.php$ new-page-%1-%2.php? [R,L]

Comment: it must be something to do that that I have only 1 line for one value

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^\&]*)